# Yii2 AuthClient Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, yii

I have a problem with FB login in my Yii application. When I try to get the user attributes, application returns internal server error. I checked all logs and found nothing.

This is my config

```
'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
            'facebook' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
                'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxx',
                'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Controller actions

```
public function actions()
{
    return
    [
        'auth' =>
        [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [$this, 'authSuccess'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

and the app crashes when it reaches this statement inside the callback

```
$attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
```

this is the $client object

```
    object(yii\authclient\clients\Facebook)#115 (20) {
  ["authUrl"]=>
  string(51) "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup"
  ["tokenUrl"]=>
  string(45) "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"
  ["apiBaseUrl"]=>
  string(26) "https://graph.facebook.com"
  ["scope"]=>
  string(5) "email"
  ["attributeNames"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "name"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "email"
  }
  ["version"]=>
  string(3) "2.0"
  ["clientId"]=>
  string(15) "xxxxxxxxxx"
  ["clientSecret"]=>
  string(32) "xxxxxxxxxx"
  ["_returnUrl":"yii\authclient\BaseOAuth":private]=>
  string(49) "http://xxxxxx.xx/auth?authclient=facebook"
  ["_curlOptions":"yii\authclient\BaseOAuth":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_accessToken":"yii\authclient\BaseOAuth":private]=>
  object(yii\authclient\OAuthToken)#117 (5) {
    ["tokenParamKey"]=>
    string(12) "access_token"
    ["tokenSecretParamKey"]=>
    string(18) "oauth_token_secret"
    ["createTimestamp"]=>
    int(1461360063)
    ["_expireDurationParamKey":"yii\authclient\OAuthToken":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_params":"yii\authclient\OAuthToken":private]=>
    array(2) {
      ["access_token"]=>
      string(175) "EAACZCvJlBssYBAF1vwxq7PMgKAsEz5GueWEpBTf3OZAGEHPrONRKVXLGggRudgsNcpHiWD2IWDlEwnVmku9qmyYvUWh2VYVPShOK6VfsQ7TID1dEozVUMgYU01raFK3IBJ2mvi5PNztnqgQ12d0yBZBYnZCVloft4FmkkYyjvwZDZD"
      ["expires"]=>
      string(7) "5181417"
    }
  }
  ["_signatureMethod":"yii\authclient\BaseOAuth":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_id":"yii\authclient\BaseClient":private]=>
  string(8) "facebook"
  ["_name":"yii\authclient\BaseClient":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_title":"yii\authclient\BaseClient":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_userAttributes":"yii\authclient\BaseClient":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_normalizeUserAttributeMap":"yii\authclient\BaseClient":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_viewOptions":"yii\authclient\BaseClient":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

**EDIT:** I just found out that it must be some problem with Yii's AuthClient (maybe FB changed response?), because I used this in another project, about a year ago and it worked just fine. Now i tried to login to that project and it does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I haven't qualification for comment...
please post your function content

```
function authSuccess($client) {
...
}
```

extra:
check your user model has implements IdentityInterface and yii\web\User it's set user attribute at login function.
you could set breakpoint on there.

Comment: it does not matter, even if I have only one line in function

$client->getUserAttributes();

it just crashes when trying to get the attributes

Comment: my User class implements IdentityInterface and works fine, anyway, it has nothing to do with AuthClient, 'cause app crashes when trying to get attributes from Facebook response, not from my user

Comment: nginx error and yii2 runtime/logs/app.log doesn't have any information ?

Comment: Or try to clean up you user model logics, filter some attributes and public function if you can.

Comment: did you use runtime facebook data for user attribute or when client register account, you've save in user model ?